# Submission forms

Tags: html, mailing-list, form-submit

Is there a correct way to go about including submission forms onto your site?

I am needing to create a form that simply allows a user to enter their email, and once they have entered it - show them a site that says thank you and we will be getting in touch with you.

Do I need specific software for this or simply just server space to store the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common goal of a [CGI script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) or scripting language.  This requires some sort of scripting language on the hosting server, such as PHP, Perl, or ASP.NET.

Create the form in HTML, and then set the action to `POST` the data to the script.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.mysite/myScript.php">
```

This script file would contain the language necessary to process the incoming information (name, email, etc.), perform some sort of action (say, emailing the data to a third party), and then displaying a thank you page to the user.